# What is the digital music sampler?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

Deus Ex: Mankind Divided launched yesterday, and the day one boast, among other DLC bonus, a "Digital Music Sampler".

While the other DLC are quite clear (bonus missions, and either a ability or a skin), that one is not explained.

Is it just the OST? A item in the game? A additional option in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Digital Music Sampler" is just a link to a `.zip` file hosted by Square Enix.

This archive regroup various music from the OST.

Answer (score 3):

The "OST Sampler" includes 9 Music Tracks from Deus Ex Trailers, the Main Menu etc. Kind of a shortened version of the complete OST.

Comment: So it is just another option on the menu? Or a "music player" inside the game, like the walkman in MGS:PW?

Answer (score 0):

Additional music tracks - check out the install directory under Extras --> Digital OST Sampler.